# jQuery extremely slow colision animation and problems with width of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I'm trying to make an animation of three circles. The circle in the middle is supposed to become larger, that works. The step function of this circle's scale animation tests whether or not the circle collides with the two other circles around it. This seems to be working, though for some reason I have to declare the width of the growing circle as a universal variable in that circle's animation function instead of calling its width method in the testcollision function itself. That's my first problem.

My second problem occurs when that middle circle grows and successfully detects collision with the two circles on either side of it. The circle to its left moves smoothly and perfectly by the animation function inside of the testcollision function. The circle to its right moves in the correct direction, but moves incredibly slowly compared to the left circle, and has a very choppy movement. I've tried lowering the duration for the circle on the right, but all this does is cause that circle to 'jump' to a certain point in the animation (e.g. duration is 10, so it will take 10 ms to jump to a certain point in its animation) before very slowly completely the full animation.

Comment: jsfiddle can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/direlelephant/eE4x7/

(Note that the circle on the right appears to stop completely, but will actually just inch very, very slowly to the right).

Comment: please update your question with the fiddle and info instead of comments..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the right animation is obviously the final position it is receiving, it must receive the left margin of the main circle + its width from the variables you have declared before, if you know in advance the boss final width you don't necessarily need to test collision all the time, the animation itself makes the illusion of collision.

change

```
var bossmoveright = boss.left + window.bosswidthfind + 6;
```

to

```
var bossmoveright = bossleft + bosswidth + 6;
```

**FIDDLE**: http://jsfiddle.net/eE4x7/1/

Comment: Thanks! Could you explain why this is? It seems like bosswidth and window.bosswidthfind give me the same value, and when I try this solution outside of jsfiddle then the right circle immediately jumps to the bossmoveright position instead of creating the illusion of collision (presumably because bossleft and bosswidth are constant values, so as soon as they're initialized they fulfill the condition to move the right circle).

Comment: The way it was, it was getting the `current position + window.bosswidthfind + 6` which was being updated and animated again to the "new" position but we can't count on javascript to sync it correctly, what we did was set it straight to the final position, animation will fix that itself